# If $|x|^2u=0$ for $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^d)$, then $\psi\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d)$ and $\operatorname{supp}(\psi)\cap B(0,10)$ imply $u(\psi)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, distribution-theory

**Problem:** Show that if $\vert x\vert^2u=0$ for $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^d)$, then for all $\psi\in\mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(\psi)\cap B(0,10)=\varnothing$ we have $u(\psi)=0.$

**My Thoughts:** I think that the problem statement is not clear, as there seems to be nothing special about $B(0,10)$. For example, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $B(0,\varepsilon)$. Note that $x\mapsto \vert x\vert^2$ is smooth on $\mathbb R^d\setminus B(0,\varepsilon)$. Therefore, if $\psi\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d)$ has $\operatorname{supp}(\psi)\cap B(0,\varepsilon)=\varnothing$, then
$$u(\psi)=\vert x\vert^2u\left(\frac{\psi}{\vert x\vert^2}\right)=0.$$
I justify the above calculation by noticing that $\psi/\vert x\vert^2\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d\setminus B(0,\varepsilon))$ and $\operatorname{supp}(\psi/\vert x\vert^2)=\operatorname{supp}(\psi)$. Also if $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^d)$, then $u\vert_{\mathbb R^d\setminus B(0,\varepsilon)}\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^d\setminus B(0,\varepsilon)).$
Therefore, it seems that the result holds for any ball centered at the origin.

---

Could anyone tell me if I am on the right track or if I have made a horrible mistake at the beginning in my understanding of the definitions?
Thank you for your time and appreciate the valuable feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there is nothing special about radius $10$. You can as well take radius $R>0$ or $\epsilon>0.$ That doesn't make the problem statement non-clear, though. But I understand that it might be confusing.

I was about to write that I do not understand how you justify $u(\psi)=|x|^2u(\psi/|x|^2)$ as $|x|$ is not a constant. But then I realized that you do not mean $|x|^2$ multiplied with $u(\psi/|x|^2)$ but the distribution $|x|^2 u$ applied to $\psi/|x|^2$. In the "bracket" notation that I'm used to it would be $\langle u, \psi \rangle = \langle |x|^2 u, |x|^{-2}\psi \rangle.$ So, yes, you are on the right track; $|x|^{-2}$ is smooth outside of the ball.